# MongoDb zero-length keys are not allowed

Tags: mongodb, insert

MongoDb, sometimes I get an error - "zero-length keys are not allowed". Is there an easy way to validate a document before inserting it into the database?
Surely it can be done programmatically , if there are easy way to validate the document?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of what you are trying to attempt in code. But it sounds like you have a "key name" that evaluates to "". And that is the cause of the error.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, an empty key

Comment: Well it's a pretty basic response since "it is not allowed". The "trying to help you" concept here is that you basically have errant code that returns "" as a key when you expect something else. So show the code.

Comment: Sometimes you want to store information and documents that you get from different sources , in my case, I wanted to store exceptions I get from PHP, as a whole. apparently, it contains empty keys and cannot be stored in the DB as is.